# MySQL query fails in Python

Tags: python, mysql

The following query works on MySQL Query Analyzer and PHP but fails in Python:

```
update home_recipient 
    set 
        process = 'PROCESS_ID', processed_on = current_timestamp
    where 
        sent_on is null or  
        timestampdiff(minute, processed_on, current_timestamp) > 60
    order by id limit 45
```

The error displayed is "You can't specify target table 'home_recipient' for update in FROM clause"

I'm using Python 2.7 and MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7.egg

The error seems to be generated by Python's driver because que query works everywhere else.

Is there a way to tell MySQL_python to stop interpreting the query and pass it "as is" to MySQL?

EDIT: This is the code that executes the query.

```
sql = """update home_recipient set process = 'PROCESS_ID', processed_on = current_timestamp
    where sent_on is null or timestampdiff(minute, processed_on, current_timestamp) > 60
    order by id limit 45"""
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
```

OK. This is getting ridiculous. Even removing everything else from the update shows the same error:

```
sql = """update home_recipient set process = 'PROCESS_ID', processed_on = current_timestamp"""
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: What's the Python code that send this query?

Comment: You should provide more information to this question. What is the python code being executed.

Answer (score 0):

The three " are the problem

```
""" This is a string for documentation"""
```

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html

```
curs.execute("update home_recipient set process = 'PROCESS_ID', processed_on = current_timestamp where sent_on is null or timestampdiff(minute, processed_on, current_timestamp) > 60 order by id limit 45")
```

If PROCESS_ID is a variable:

```
curs.execute( 'update home_recipient set process=:PROCESS_ID, processed_on = current_timestamp where sent_on is null or timestampdiff(minute, processed_on, current_timestamp) > 60 order by id limit 45', [PROCESS_ID])
```

Comment: -1 FIRSTLY, the three double-quotes are NOT the problem. They are just another way of delimiting string constants. That is NOT a comment. Comments start with `#`, and are ignored. A doc-string is just a string (delimited however you like) at the start of (e.g.) a function/method, and is NOT ignored. If the text inside the `"""` quotes was being ignored, how come the table name gets mentioned in the error message?? SECONDLY, you should NOT do your own quoting when substituting parameters. See this link: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Thanks John, I will use this notation. I remember a similar method in delphi.